# Calculate the probability of finding a value in a submatrix of a 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

This is probably a stupid question, but I am trying to replace the pixel values of an image with the probability of finding that value in the neighbourhood of the pixel.

Suppose we have an 100x100 image named `img`. I want to to sample the image in blocks of 5x5 (or some other square with odd sides), determine the probability of each value in the sample and then replace the pixel value with the probability of that value, according to the formula:

[image: P(z_k) = n_K/(MN)]

where n<sub>k</sub> is the number of times the value of z<sub>k</sub> occurs and NM is the product of my sample side lengths (in this case 5x5). So for an 8-bit image, we have z<sub>i</sub>, i = 0, 1, ..., 255.
If pixel j has the value z<sub>k</sub> it should then be replaced with P(z<sub>k</sub>) for the 5x5 sample. I also need to handle edges in some way, but right now, my only solution is a mess of `for` loops that takes forever to compute. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

### EDIT

This is my current code, which takes about a minute and a half to compute for a 3.7 MPixel 8-bit grayscale image:

```
import numpy as np
area = np.array([7, 7])

def probability(image, area):
    dx, dy = area
    dxx, dyy = area//2
    imout = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=np.float64)
    image = np.pad(image, dxx, 'edge')
    shape = (image.shape[0] - dx + 1, image.shape[1] - dy +1, dx,dy)
    strides = 2*image.strides
    patches = stride_tricks.as_strided(image,shape=shape, strides=strides)
    pa = patches.reshape(image.shape[0] - dx + 1, image.shape[1] - dy +1, dx*dy)
    i = j = 0
    for x in pa:
        for y in x:
            values, inverse, counts = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
            p = counts/y.size
            idx = inverse[y.size//2]
            imout[i,j] = p[idx]
            j += 1
        i += 1
        j = 0
    return imout

p = probability(file[0, :20, :20], (10,10), area)
pixel = file[0, 10, 10]
print('image array:\n', file[0, 7:14, 7:14])
print('Probability for pixel value {} is: {:0.3f}'.format(pixel, p[1]))

image array:
 [[49 58 53 60 61 50 51]
 [56 49 57 50 48 49 58]
 [51 59 56 55 45 56 51]
 [57 58 61 49 56 54 65]
 [46 52 47 52 46 45 44]
 [46 57 56 60 56 56 57]
 [63 58 36 67 47 60 43]]
Probability for pixel value 49 is: 0.082
```

Comment: would be nice if you had some code provided at least for the setup of problem.

Comment: you basically have to move a `N*M` size window on a `100*100` image? or `N*N`, actually once you say the window is square

Comment: Sounds like a really interesting question. But without any code provided you most probably won't find an answer.

Comment: I updated the question with some code to show how I solve the task at the moment. As you can see it is not the most elegant solution and it takes a 2 µs to find just one probability, so doing that for 3.7 million pixels is still going to take me 850.000 seconds.

Comment: @Evgeny, yes, you are correct. I have solved related problems using `stride_tricks` with impressive speed gains, but I can't wrap my head around this one. I tried using the suggestion in the answer below, but that actually made it slower.

Comment: BTW, I misread my own timing, so it's actually 2 ms rather than 2 µs. and the total runtime for 3.7 million pixels is just under 5 minutes for the code in my question, but 21 minutes if I implement the changes suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution to this problem is to use [`pop_bilateral()`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html#pop-bilateral) from the module [`skimage.filters.rank`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html) and divide by the sum of pixels in the sample block.

The `pop_bilateral()` function counts the local number of pixels in the neighborhood with the constraint that only pixels with a gray-scale value inside the interval `[g-s0,g+s1]` will be counted. In this interval, `g` is the value of the center pixel and `s0` and `s1` are integer value parameters. So by setting `s0 = s1 = 1`, only the pixels with exactly the value `g` will be counted. The output is then  a 2-D array with the same datatype as the input array. By converting the output array to a `np.float64` type and then dividing by the the sum of pixels in the neighborhood, the resulting array will consist of the probabilities for each pixel given their neighborhoods.

Because `pop_bilateral()` does not alter the input in any way before counting, it is necesseray to do the array padding before counting and then slice the result afterwards. Using this method reduces the calculation time for a 3.7 MPixel image from 127 seconds to 1.02 seconds.

Below is the complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.filters.rank as rank
from timeit import timeit

image = array([[54, 52, 51, 52, 52, 58, 51, 45, 61, 59],
       [65, 61, 51, 53, 48, 53, 53, 59, 54, 48],
       [52, 44, 46, 53, 75, 45, 59, 65, 59, 58],
       [68, 53, 60, 53, 54, 53, 59, 59, 65, 52],
       [55, 54, 52, 53, 56, 59, 69, 62, 55, 53],
       [47, 53, 50, 59, 68, 53, 71, 58, 51, 59],
       [66, 61, 39, 53, 54, 56, 52, 50, 55, 64],
       [58, 54, 53, 46, 49, 49, 59, 49, 58, 53],
       [54, 43, 42, 53, 52, 65, 68, 56, 49, 57],
       [65, 51, 52, 63, 58, 59, 52, 51, 59, 56]], dtype=uint8)

area = np.array([7,7])

def probability(image, area):
    dx, dy = area
    dxx, dyy = area//2
    image = np.pad(image, dxx, 'reflect')
    imout = (rank.pop_bilateral(image,
                                np.ones(area),
                                s0=1,
                                s1=1).astype(
            np.float64)/(dx*dy))[dxx:-dxx,dxx:-dxx]
    return imout

p = probability(image, area)
setup = 'from __main__ import probability, image, area; import numpy as np; import skimage.filters.rank as rank'
num = 1
t1 = timeit('probability(file[0, :10, :10], area)', setup=setup, number=num)
print('probability array:\n ', p)
print('probability run time: {:.3f}'.format(t1))
probability array:
  [[0.02 0.12 0.06 0.1  0.06 0.02 0.02 0.06 0.04 0.43]
 [0.04 0.08 0.06 0.24 0.04 0.22 0.24 0.24 0.08 0.04]
 [0.14 0.04 0.02 0.27 0.02 0.04 0.2  0.06 0.27 0.06]
 [0.02 0.18 0.02 0.22 0.06 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.08 0.06]
 [0.02 0.12 0.04 0.24 0.04 0.16 0.02 0.02 0.08 0.08]
 [0.02 0.22 0.02 0.1  0.04 0.16 0.02 0.08 0.04 0.22]
 [0.02 0.04 0.02 0.18 0.08 0.06 0.08 0.02 0.08 0.02]
 [0.02 0.14 0.16 0.02 0.06 0.1  0.12 0.14 0.08 0.04]
 [0.12 0.08 0.04 0.14 0.1  0.04 0.06 0.08 0.2  0.04]
 [0.02 0.04 0.06 0.02 0.02 0.08 0.1  0.02 0.1  0.1 ]]
probability run time: 0.0006
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this runs faster.  Looking for only the values you actually have in the array means you should save time by not attempting to count values that are not present.  **np.bincount()** starts counting from zero. **np.histogram** lets you specify bin values, and in the example you gave the lowest value in the array is 36.

Using the 7 x 7 pixel array you showed:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[49, 58, 53, 60, 61, 50, 51],
                [56, 49, 57, 50, 48, 49, 58],
                [51, 59, 56, 55, 45, 56, 51],
                [57, 58, 61, 49, 56, 54, 65],
                [46, 52, 47, 52, 46, 45, 44],
                [46, 57, 56, 60, 56, 56, 57],
                [63, 58, 36, 67, 47, 60, 43]])
values = np.unique(arr)
prob = np.histogram(arr, values)[0] / arr.size
print(dict(zip(values, prob)))
```

Here's the output:

```
{36: 0.02040816326530612, 43: 0.02040816326530612, 44: 0.02040816326530612, 
45: 0.04081632653061224, 46: 0.061224489795918366, 47: 0.04081632653061224, 
48: 0.02040816326530612, 49: 0.08163265306122448, 50: 0.04081632653061224, 
51: 0.061224489795918366, 52: 0.04081632653061224, 53: 0.02040816326530612, 
54: 0.02040816326530612, 55: 0.02040816326530612, 56: 0.14285714285714285, 
57: 0.08163265306122448, 58: 0.08163265306122448, 59: 0.02040816326530612, 
60: 0.061224489795918366, 61: 0.04081632653061224, 63: 0.02040816326530612, 
65: 0.04081632653061224}
```

Edit: as for the submatrix part of your problem: building a **list** from an array using a Python for loop seems slow to me.  If you can guarantee that the submatrix size evenly divides the full array size in both dimensions, you could do this:

```
row_div, col_div = 5, 5   # or whatever values you need
for row in np.split(arr, row_div):
    for rotated in np.split(row.T, col_div):
        submatrix = rotated.T
        # do stuff with submatrix
```

You could also use 2-dimensional slicing: `submatrix = arr[r1:r2, c1:c2]`, where the indices are calculated by for loops, but you can use larger strides.

Comment: The thing is, if I have an MxN matrix, then I need to calculate the probability for each and every element in the matrix, which means that I need to pad the matrix in order to handle edges, but it also means that `np.split()` will probably not work because I cannot use it to divide the MxN matrix into overlapping submatrices, as far as I know.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but implementing your solution with `np.histogram()` actually made the function slower by a factor of 10. I would have expected to actually be faster by at least a few percent.

Comment: I see now that it's a scaling issue. For one submatrix, it is slower, but when I use it on the entire image array, it is a lot faster, but it still takes a minute and a half, which is far too slow for my setup. Especially when considering that calculating the entropy for the same image takes less than 10 seconds. I wonder why the `scipy.stats` package does not have a function for doing this rather simple calculation.